# Python : Could not cast a numpy array into a string

Tags: python, replace, casting

I wrote a code which is meant to replace a tag from a string with a number extracted from an array.

This is part of a bigger project but I only isolated the problematic part

```
# import numpy as np
time_vect = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
string = "T= <T>"
for i in range(0, len(time_vect),1):
    string = string.replace("<T>", str(time_vect[i]))
    print(string)
```

However the replace function seems to totally ignore the value. When I run the code I get this output :

```
T= 0
T= 0
T= 0
T= 0
T= 0
T= 0
T= 0
T= 0
T= 0
T= 0
```

When I assign the value manually, I get the expected result

```
>> print(string.replace("<T>", str(time_vect[3])))
T= 3
```

I tried to convert the numpy.int32 type into native int type but it did not solve the problem

```
string = string.replace("<T>", str(time_vect[i].item()))
```

I could not find any leads on the net so I would be thankful if I could get some support :)

Comment: You are replacing the "<T>" in the first iteration, after that the replace function can't find it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reassing `string` in the loop.
After the first iteration, your string no longer contains `<T>` so there is nothing to replace it is "T= 0", so replacing `<T>` does nothing.

```
import numpy as np
time_vect = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
string = "T = <T>"
for i in range(0, len(time_vect),1):
    s = string.replace("<T>", str(time_vect[i]))
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as @Vulwsztyn, without an intermediate variable :

```
time_vect = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
string = "T= <T>"
for i in range(0, len(time_vect),1):
    print(string.replace("<T>", str(time_vect[i])))
```

Comment: Well noted ! Thanks